# Show and hide elements within CSS column-count

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a long list of items that I am filtering using a jQuery checkbox filter.

The list is split into three columns using the css rule: `column-count`.

http://jsfiddle.net/jamisthis/LSz6V/2/

On the site I'm working on there is a noticeable pause after a checkbox is selected and the elements are rearranged. This doesn't happen is the 'slow' parameter is taken away.

The filtering also appears to be smoother in the fiddle, if the `column-count` rule is taken away.

What is causing my code to pause after a checkbox is selected?

Thanks.

Comment: Using 'Slow' means you are simultaneously animating many items at once. Using columns means that the browser must calculate how many items should be in each column when you make the changes. Both of those things affect performance.

Comment: it  looks a lot like this : http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/JFdEk , but wit CSS transition and size

Comment: Thanks for your comments. As a temporary solution it seems using `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` has a performance advantage (or at least appears to) over `.show() and .hide()`.